# How to monitor Seed method in an Azure Deployment?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a Seed method that - this time around - does quite a bit of work.  It takes about 10 minutes locally and has been running in Azure (Website) for 20 minutes.

The only feedback I have is 1) monitoring the Azure database for changes that reflect a successful seed - difficult for AddOrUpdate, and 2) the fact that my Package Manager Console still says "Running Seed Method".

Is there any other way to get more insight into what stage / method / etc the seed method is on, while it's running as part of a migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application is running on Windows Azure Websites, you can instrument your seed and migration methods with calls to `System.Diagnostics.Trace` and then you can stream the log to the command line:

```
azure site log tail mysite
```

For details on the procedure refer to [Streaming Diagnostics Trace Logging from the Azure Command Line (plus Glimpse!)](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/StreamingDiagnosticsTraceLoggingFromTheAzureCommandLinePlusGlimpse.aspx) and [How to debug an application in Windows Azure Web Sites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/diagnostics-logging-and-instrumentation/#streamlogs).

You can also view the log stream in Visual Studio. As described in [Announcing the release of Windows Azure SDK 2.0 for .NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/04/30/announcing-the-release-of-windows-azure-sdk-2-0-for-net.aspx), this can be done in the Server Explorer, connecting to the web site and selecting the `View Streaming Logs in Output Window` command.

Comment: Is there any way to seed tracing to the package manager console so I don't have to leave VS while I seed/publish?

Comment: Yes. I've updated my answer with instructions on how to stream the log to Visual Studio's Output Window.